# How did Taliesin come to be wrapped in a skin in icy waters?

Tags: arthurian, stephen-r-lawhead

[Stephen R Lawhead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_R._Lawhead)'s Arthurian legend fantasy series, [The Pendragon Cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendragon_Cycle), starts with [*Taliesin*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendragon_Cycle#Taliesin) which follows events from before Merlin or Arthur. The unlucky Elphin finds a baby wrapped in skins under the icy waters as he's trying to catch fish. The baby is alive, Elphin adopts him and calls him Taliesin. Elphin's luck reverses from that point on... Does the series ever explain who did this to Taliesin and why?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, Taliesin's origins are left a mystery.

Comment: An answer would have to be found in the medieval literature about Taliesin which includes a story of his origins involving a lot of magic, if I remember correctly.